# Delegating an event to the whole object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-delegation

I have a jQuery plugin (which I've written) which has an option to match an optional child selector. Ie: If I have this markup:

```
<div class="header">
  <a id="item-name">Blah</a>
  <span class="some-data">Numbers and Stuff</a>
  <span class="other-data">Bananas</a>
</div>
```

Orignally, I delegated the click event to the whole .header using:

```
headerDiv.on('click', function () {
```

But then needed to limit the click to only the anchor, so to maintain compatibility, I used the alternative syntax:

```
headerDiv.on('click',headerSelector, function () {
```

Where `headerSelector`, by default is `*`, but I could pass `a` to limit it to just the anchor. The default `*` selector I'm now using seems problematic though, sometimes clicks aren't registered. Is there a proper way to match the element itself when using the delegated event syntax?

Comment: please show code of the event binder in  your plugin

Answer (score 0):

By default you can do

`headerSelector = headerDiv`

I think it will be equal to `headerDiv.on('click', function () {`

Comment: I think this will not work because it will look for headerDiv inside headerDiv

Answer (score 0):

Use document as the parent element and inside selector use headerDiv and then a *. if child is given replace * with it.

```
$(document).on('click', "headerDiv *", function(){})
```